# Can we detect moving "in" and "out" without timers?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, latch

I wish to automate my light-bulb such that when I enter it turns on and turns off when I exit.

So there are two sensors **A** and **B**.
**A** then **B** : Light ON
**B** then **A** : Light OFF

I was wondering if it is possible to do this without using timers.
**Is there any way to distinguish A first then B from B first then A without using timers?**

Can latches be cleverly used for this?

Comment: What kind of sensor? Because pressure plates are going to be different than motion sensors. You can do this with flip-flops. Basically you need latches, toggles, and edge-detectors.

Comment: I'm thinking of Reflective Active High IR sensors. But better suggestions are welcome. How can we know if its moving in or moving out without two sensors? If I understood correctly, the design you suggested will turn the light off when a second person enters.

Comment: I haven't though it through very carefully but with a toggling latch and edge trigger you only need one sensor, but it indeed won't differentiate between direction. You can double it up so it does but I haven't thought completely about how to do that. Should be possible though. It basically becomes building a state machine out of latches and flip flops.

Comment: What will happen if 2 people walk in and 1 person walks out?

Comment: And what happens if 2 people walk in and 15 people walk out? ;) Worse, what's the meaning of the English word ***left*** in the following sentence: "5 people have left and 15 people are left"? Does *left* mean going? Or staying? (May as well add more puzzles to solve.) I think we need specifications.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack MOAR LOGIC! lol. Start building counters out of relays to keep track of the number of people going in and out. I don't recommend going beyond  3 people. Instead of a massive binary counter with relay latches, I recommend using a motorized counting wheel with notches that a hit limit switch to stop the wheel turning to keep count and hits a switch between at count 0 and 1 to toggle the light on and off with an end stop so it can't loop around and hit the switch. Mechanically simpler and you can accomodate more people with more notches rather than having a ton of relays.

Comment: You can also add a switch at the very end next to the end stop to light up a sign for for "No Admittance, Full occupancy." Might as well label the motorized wheel with numbers too and turn it into a readout so people entering know how many people are already inside.

Comment: Relays are good. Something [like this](https://youtu.be/n3wPBcmSb2U) will work just fine, with only a little added coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is with a microcontroller, but that's cheating.

The first "hard-core" idea that springs to mind is that if you position your sensors close enough together, less than the width of the human body, they can form quadrature, like this:

[image]

You can use quadrature pairs as triggers to count up or down, by defining one of them as a "direction" signal, and the other as a clock (trigger). Say we define A to represent direction. The presence of a person causes A to be high, then a few milliseconds later causes B to rise, and we can use this condition to signal a person entering. If however, A is low when B is triggered, the person must be moving in the opposite direction.

There are counter ICs designed to operate from just such a quadrature pair, one of them being the [74HC191](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC191.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flEJfY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Up to 15 people can occupy the room, each one incrementing the counter on entry, and decrementing it on exit. The OR gates simply create a high signal if any of the Q outputs are high. In other words, only when the counter is zero (all Q bits are low) is the output low.

I think there must be ways to improve reliability, but that's one idea, in a nutshell.

Comment: Great answer sir. Thanks a lot.